# Fixed grid where each grid item keeps its dimension no matter what content it holds

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am trying to make a fixed grid, that doesn't resize no matter what content is added in each individual `div`. I have tried to use `overflow:hidden` and the `minmax()`.

The idea is that each individual box / section will hold text / images centred in each box. Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #15243a;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Whyte";
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
}

.grid-view div {
  border: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 99;
}

.top-nav {
  grid-column: 1/12;
}

.top-left-1 {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 2/5;
}

.top-mid-left-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 5;
}

.top-mid-left-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 5;
}

.top-mid-left-3 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 5;
}

.mid-left-span {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 6;
}

.bot-left-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 7;
}

.bot-left-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 7;
}

.bot-left-3 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 7;
}

.mid-vertical-col {
  grid-column: 4/6;
  grid-row: 2/8;
}

.top-ill-con {
  grid-column: 6/8;
  grid-row: 2/4;
}

.mid-top-sq-1 {
  grid-column: 6;
  grid-row: 4;
}

.mid-top-sq-2 {
  grid-column: 6;
  grid-row: 5;
}

.mid-top-sq-3 {
  grid-column: 6;
  grid-row: 6;
}

.mid-top-sq-4 {
  grid-column: 6;
  grid-row: 7;
}

.top-right-box {
  grid-column: 10 / 12;
  grid-row: 2/6;
}

.mid-mid {
  grid-column: 7/9;
  grid-row: 4/6;
}

.bottom-span {
  grid-column: 8/10;
  grid-row: 7;
}

.bot-nav {
  grid-column: 1/12;
}
```

```html
    <div class="grid grid-view">
      <div class="top-nav"></div>
      <div class="top-left-1"></div>
      <div class="top-mid-left-1"></div>
      <div class="top-mid-left-2"></div>
      <div class="top-mid-left-3"></div>
      <div class="mid-left-span"></div>
      <div class="bot-left-1"></div>
      <div class="bot-left-2"></div>
      <div class="bot-left-3"></div>
      <div class="mid-vertical-col"></div>
      <div class="top-ill-con"></div>
      <div class="mid-top-sq-1"></div>
      <div class="mid-top-sq-2"></div>
      <div class="mid-top-sq-3"></div>
      <div class="mid-top-sq-4"></div>
      <div class="mid-mid"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div class="top-right-box"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div class="bottom-span"></div>
      <div class="bot-nav"></div>
    </div>
```

Here is a Codepen as well : https://codepen.io/NiallColman49/pen/xxWwdZx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code below, every grid item will keep its width and height no matter what content in it. If there is more content than the given space, there will be a scroll in it. What I did different is to set on `.grid` fixed number of `columns` and `rows`. Then I added `overflow:auto` on each `.grid-view div` (there are comments in the CSS code, where I added things).

```css
body {
  background-color: #15243a;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Whyte";
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  /* lines I added */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(11, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(11, calc(100vh / 8));
}

.grid-view div {
  border: 1px solid white;
  /* line I added */
  overflow: auto;
}

.top-nav {
  grid-column: 1/12;
}

.top-left-1 {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 2/5;
}

.top-mid-left-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 5;
}

.top-mid-left-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 5;
}

.top-mid-left-3 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 5;
}

.mid-left-span {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 6;
}

.bot-left-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 7;
}

.bot-left-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 7;
}

.bot-left-3 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 7;
}

.mid-vertical-col {
  grid-column: 4/6;
  grid-row: 2/8;
}

.top-ill-con {
  grid-column: 6/8;
  grid-row: 2/4;
}

.mid-top-sq-1 {
  grid-column: 6;
  grid-row: 4;
}

.mid-top-sq-2 {
  grid-column: 6;
  grid-row: 5;
}

.mid-top-sq-3 {
  grid-column: 6;
  grid-row: 6;
}

.mid-top-sq-4 {
  grid-column: 6;
  grid-row: 7;
}

.top-right-box {
  grid-column: 10 / 12;
  grid-row: 2/6;
}

.mid-mid {
  grid-column: 7/9;
  grid-row: 4/6;
}

.bottom-span {
  grid-column: 8/10;
  grid-row: 7;
}

.bot-nav {
  grid-column: 1/12;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid grid-view">
  <div class="top-nav"></div>
  <div class="top-left-1"></div>
  <div class="top-mid-left-1"></div>
  <div class="top-mid-left-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div class="top-mid-left-3"></div>
  <div class="mid-left-span"></div>
  <div class="bot-left-1"></div>
  <div class="bot-left-2"></div>
  <div class="bot-left-3"></div>
  <div class="mid-vertical-col"></div>
  <div class="top-ill-con"></div>
  <div class="mid-top-sq-1"></div>
  <div class="mid-top-sq-2"></div>
  <div class="mid-top-sq-3"></div>
  <div class="mid-top-sq-4"></div>
  <div class="mid-mid"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="top-right-box"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="bottom-span"></div>
  <div class="bot-nav"></div>
</div>
```